# ハナクソの秘密をそっと話くそう Is it just a pun on 話そう?

Tags: meaning

The character just says out of the blue (in order to lighten the mood) :

> ハナクソの秘密をそっと話{はな}くそう!! [with dots above the seconds は、な、く and そ]

Is it just a pun on 話そう？ => Let's talk discretely about the secret of the snot!!

Like, I don't know, if there was a verb "to sno" in English meaning "to speak" and the speaker voluntarily pronounced it "snoT" instead of "sno" : Let's snoT discretely about the secret of the snot!!

Comment: By the way, Japanese for "cheesy joke" is 寒いギャグ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically correct would be 話そう, without the く. But in order to make it similar to ハナクソ (similar words tend to be funny, right?), only one single hiragana く is added. Your analogy in English fits this perfectly. The く functions the same way as your T in snoT.